# Equivalent Vitali Covering Properties for Differentiation Bases

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

*N.B. In what follows below, we work exclusively with the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.*

**Def 1** For each $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, let $\mathcal{B}(x)$ be a collection of bounded open sets $R$ containing $x$ such that there exists a sequence $\left\{R_{k}\right\}\subset\mathcal{B}(x)$ tending to $\left\{x\right\}$. We say that $\mathcal{B}:=\bigcup\mathcal{B}(x)$ is a *differentiation basis*. If for $R\in\mathcal{B}$, $x\in R$ implies $R\in\mathcal{B}(x)$, we say that $\mathcal{B}$ is a *Busemann-Feller differentiation basis*. (Hereafter, all differentiation bases will be BF.)

**Def 2**
Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a measurable set. $V\subset\mathcal{B}$ is a *$\mathcal{B}$-Vitali covering* of $A$ if for each $x\in A$ there exists a sequence $\left\{R_{k}\right\}\subset V$ such that $x\in R_{k}$ and $\text{diam }R_{k}\rightarrow 0$.

**Def 3**  We say that a basis $\mathcal{B}$ has the $V_{q}$ property, where $1<q<\infty$, if there exists  constant $C$ such that for every measurable set $A$, for every $\mathcal{B}$-Vitali covering of $A$, and for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a countable subcollection $\left\{R_{k}\right\}\subset V$ satisfying

1. $\left|A\setminus\bigcup R_{k}\right|=0$, $\left|\bigcup R_{k}\setminus A\right|\leq\varepsilon$
2. $\left\|\sum \chi_{R_{k}}\right\|_{L^{q}}\leq C\left|A\right|^{1/q}$

Define the upper and lower derivatives of $\int f$ at $x$ respectively by
$$\overline{D}\left(\int f,x\right):=\sup_{\left\{R_{k}\right\}}\limsup_{k}\dfrac{1}{\left|R_{k}\right|}\int_{R_{k}}f, \ \underline{D}\left(\int f,x\right):=\inf_{\left\{R_{k}\right\}}\liminf_{k}\dfrac{1}{\left|R_{k}\right|}\int_{R_{k}}f$$
where the supremum and infimum are respectively taken over all sequences $\left\{R_{k}\right\}\subset\mathcal{B}(x)$ with $\text{diam} R_{k}\rightarrow 0$.

It has been shown by [A. Cordoba and R. Fefferman](http://www.pnas.org/content/74/6/2211.full.pdf) [Theorem 2, p. 2212] that the $V_{q}$ property is equivalent to the property that $\mathcal{B}$ differentiates $\int f$ a.e., for $f\in L_{loc}^{p}$, where $1/p+1/q=1$; i.e.,
$$\overline{D}\left(\int f,x\right)=\underline{D}\left(\int f,x\right)=f(x) \ a.e.,$$

It has also been shown by [C.A. Hayes](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102867223) [Theorem 2.4, p. 178] that Definition 3 with condition 2 replaced by condition 2*
$$\left\|\sum_{k}\chi_{R_{k}}-\chi_{\bigcup R_{k}}\right\|_{L^{q}}\leq\varepsilon$$
is equivalent to the differentiation property stated above.

My question is whether there is a proof of the equivalence of Cordoba's $V_{q}$ property and Hayes's $V_{q}$ property, which does not use the full result that each is equivalent to the differentiation property.